# Matlab S Function Builder how to change compiler to g++

Tags: c++, matlab

First of all thanks a lot for reading this post and being able to help.

I am trying to compile a C++ code in S-Function Builder. When I click on "build" matlab gives me an error which is:

> error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘/’ token

I know that Matlab maybe uses a C compiler but not C++ compiler.

how can I change to C++ compiler in S-Function builder?
I have tried with mex -setup c++ but it des not work. And with mbuild -setup c++ neither.

I am working on Ubuntu.

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 1):

To compile an s-function as c++ you should be able to use the below command
in the command window. It's important that the source file extension be .cpp or it will not treat it like a c++ function.

```
mex s_function.cpp
```

From the error you're getting, however, it sounds like you have a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks to answering. I do "mex s_function.cpp" but it can not find te headers (.h). This is because they are not in current folder, so how can indicate the path of headers? Thanks a lot

Comment: You should be able to use the -I flag to tell it where include files are. See this matlab [answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/4590-include-files)